# HTML form submit button to execute print statement

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm pretty new to html coding. I am trying to implement a simple application that asks the user to input a salutation, first name, and last name. Upon submission, instead of storing the names into a database, I just want an alert or print statement to appear below the form itself that says `"Welcome" + salutation + last name`.

I thought I could just implement this using a simple python script and an html file that holds all the contents. Is there something more to this?

***app.py***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('form.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

***form.html***

```
<html lang="en">
  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Gettin' a feel for docker</h1>
        <form class="form" method= "post" onSubmit= "alert('Welcome')">
          <label for="salutation" class="sr-only">Salutation</label>
          <input type="salutation" name="salutation" id="salutation" class="form-control" required autofocus><br>
          <label for="firstName" class="sr-only">First Name</label>
          <input type="name" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control" required autofocus><br>
          <label for="lastName" class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
          <input type="name" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control"  required><br>

          <button id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to dynamically display the results of the user input upon a button click, you will have to use `jquery`.

```
<html>
 <header>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </header>
  <body>
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <input type='text' id='salutation'>
      <input type='text' id='firstname'>
      <input type='text' id='lastname'>
      <button class='get_greeting'>Display</button>
      <div class='results'></div>
    </div>
  </body>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.wrapper').on('click', '.get_greeting', function(){
       $('.results').html('<p>Welcome, '+$('#salutation').val()+' '+$('#firstname').val()+' '+$('#lastname').val()+'</p>')
     });
   });
 </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume hitting "display" should automatically give an output without any add ons or installs? I am not getting an output.

Comment: @whatanoob As long as you include `jquery` (`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com....`), use the javascript posted, and ensure that the `input` `id`s are correct, it will work.

Comment: Hmm I tried replacing my code with yours, and the display button still doesn't work for me.

Comment: @whatanoob Did you replace your entire `form.html` file with my code above? It works when I load it in my browser.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that you made an edit to your code. It works now. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @whatanoob Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

The code as per your requirement in `form.html` should be as follow :

```
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Gettin' a feel for docker</h1>
        <form class="form" method= "post" onSubmit= "alert('Welcome')">
          <label for="salutation" class="sr-only">Salutation</label>
          <input type="salutation" name="salutation" id="salutation" class="form-control" required autofocus><br>
          <label for="firstName" class="sr-only">First Name</label>
          <input type="name" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control" required autofocus><br>
          <label for="lastName" class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
          <input type="name" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control"  required><br>
          <button id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button" onclick="show_alert()">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function show_alert(){
          alert("Welcome, "+ document.getElementById('salutation').value + " " + document.getElementById('firstName').value + " " + document.getElementById('lastName').value);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```